# Name of classic MC protective personality type?

Tags: tropes

What is someone who is protective of another character enough to get hurt for them called? Pretty much all MCs in anime with fighting but I wanna know a specific name. Like Naruto protecting his friends or Thor from Absolute Duo protecting Julie and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

This is what they call, a [hero](http://tvtropes.org/Main/TheHero). Or as not all MC's are hero's the [Protagonist](http://tvtropes.org/Main/TheProtagonist). They tend to [take the bullet](http://tvtropes.org/Main/TakingTheBullet), make the [heroic sacrifice](http://tvtropes.org/Main/HeroicSacrifice) and until their [plot driven armor](http://tvtropes.org/Main/StoryDrivenInvulnerability) worn out, they will keep doing so.